# Why is my HTML-CSS progress bar losing its coloring?

Tags: html, css, colors, formatting, progress-bar

I have this code for a progress bar depicting the life cycle a support ticket might go through:

```css
.container {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.progressbar {
  counter-reset: step;
}

.progressbar li { /*name of incomplete tasks */
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #7d7d7d;
}

.progressbar li:before { /*circle of incomplete tasks */
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  counter-increment: step;
  line-height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

.progressbar li:after { /* line preceding incomplete tasks */
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  top: 12px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}

.progressbar li.done { /* check mark and name of completed tasks */
  color: #55b776;
}

.progressbar li.done:before { /* circles of completed tasks */
  border-color: #55b776;
  content: "\2713";
}

.progressbar li.done+li:after { /* line following completed tasks */
  background-color: #55b776;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="done">Open</li>
    <li class="done">In Progress</li>
    <li>With Engineering</li>
    <li>Resolution Provided</li>
    <li>Closed</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It works perfectly, but when I try to include it in a formatted document, the colored bar connecting the different 'stages' either loses its color or stops existing. I think it is because of different instances of background-color overriding each other, but whether this is the case or not I am not sure how I can correct or prevent his from happening. Can someone please help me understand what I may not be grasping?

Here is where the problem arises:

```css
.container {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.progressbar {
  counter-reset: step;
}

.progressbar li {
  /*name of incomplete tasks */
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #7d7d7d;
}

.progressbar li:before {
  /*circle of incomplete tasks */
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  counter-increment: step;
  line-height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

.progressbar li:after {
  /* line preceding incomplete tasks */
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  top: 12px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}

.progressbar li.done {
  /* check mark and name of completed tasks */
  color: #55b776;
}

.progressbar li.done:before {
  /* circles of completed tasks */
  border-color: #55b776;
  content: "\2713";
}

.progressbar li.done+li:after {
  /* line following completed tasks */
  background-color: #55b776;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<div style="width:650px; background-color:#EEEEEE;">
<header>
  <h1>
    COMPANY
  </h1>
  </header>
  <table width="95%" align="center" cellpadding="10" style="width:95%; background-color: #666666;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:15px">Case Number: 0000000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table cellpadding="10">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:35px">Date Opened: 10/31/2017 at 2:13 PM</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table width="95%" align="center" cellpadding="10" style="width:95%;background-color:white;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:20px;">
          You are receiving this email because your case has been updated. Your case details and any updates can be found below this message.
          <br /> If you wish to post a comment to the case you can simply reply to this email and your case will be updated. If you would like to include a screenshot or relevant log files you can do so by including them in your reply.
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" style="text-align: center;">
          <span class="container">
            <ul class="progressbar">
              <li class="done">Open</li>
              <li class="done">In Progress</li>
              <li>With Engineering</li>
              <li>Resolution Provided</li>
              <li>Closed</li>
            </ul>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:20px;">
      In order to proceed with your case we will need additional information or clarification on the reported issue. Please provide the requested information within the next 4 days. If no response is received during this time we will temporarily archive your
      case. Once you are ready to continue with simply reply to one of the case emails.
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
        <td>
           <table cellpadding="5" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td width="150" style="width:150px;background-color:#EEEEEE;padding-left:20px;border-left:10px solid white;">
                   <span style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">Subject</span>
                 </td>
                 <td width="350" style="width:350px;border:1px solid #EEEEEE;">TICKET TITLE HERE</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td width="150" style="width:150px; background-color:#EEEEEE;padding-left:20px;border-left:10px solid white;">
                   <span style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">Description</span>
                 </td>
                 <td width="350" style="width:350px;border:1px solid #EEEEEE;">TICKET DESCRIPTION HERE</td>
               </tr>
             </tbody>
           </table>
         </td>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index: -1;` is pushing the `:after` pseudo elements behind the other elements in the document.

Instead, remove the `z-index` from `:after` and add a `z-index` with a positive value to `:before`.

```css
.container {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.progressbar {
  counter-reset: step;
}

.progressbar li {
  /*name of incomplete tasks */
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #7d7d7d;
}

.progressbar li:before {
  /*circle of incomplete tasks */
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  counter-increment: step;
  line-height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative; /* ---------------- Added */
  z-index: 1; /* ------------------------ Added */
}

.progressbar li:after {
  /* line preceding incomplete tasks */
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  top: 12px;
  left: -50%;
}

.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}

.progressbar li.done {
  /* check mark and name of completed tasks */
  color: #55b776;
}

.progressbar li.done:before {
  /* circles of completed tasks */
  border-color: #55b776;
  content: "\2713";
}

.progressbar li.done+li:after {
  /* line following completed tasks */
  background-color: #55b776;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<div style="width:650px; background-color:#EEEEEE;">
<header>
  <h1>
    COMPANY
  </h1>
  </header>
  <table width="95%" align="center" cellpadding="10" style="width:95%; background-color: #666666;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:15px">Case Number: 0000000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table cellpadding="10">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:35px">Date Opened: 10/31/2017 at 2:13 PM</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table width="95%" align="center" cellpadding="10" style="width:95%;background-color:white;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:20px;">
          You are receiving this email because your case has been updated. Your case details and any updates can be found below this message.
          <br /> If you wish to post a comment to the case you can simply reply to this email and your case will be updated. If you would like to include a screenshot or relevant log files you can do so by including them in your reply.
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" style="text-align: center;">
          <span class="container">
            <ul class="progressbar">
              <li class="done">Open</li>
              <li class="done">In Progress</li>
              <li>With Engineering</li>
              <li>Resolution Provided</li>
              <li>Closed</li>
            </ul>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:20px;">
      In order to proceed with your case we will need additional information or clarification on the reported issue. Please provide the requested information within the next 4 days. If no response is received during this time we will temporarily archive your
      case. Once you are ready to continue with simply reply to one of the case emails.
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
        <td>
           <table cellpadding="5" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td width="150" style="width:150px;background-color:#EEEEEE;padding-left:20px;border-left:10px solid white;">
                   <span style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">Subject</span>
                 </td>
                 <td width="350" style="width:350px;border:1px solid #EEEEEE;">TICKET TITLE HERE</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td width="150" style="width:150px; background-color:#EEEEEE;padding-left:20px;border-left:10px solid white;">
                   <span style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">Description</span>
                 </td>
                 <td width="350" style="width:350px;border:1px solid #EEEEEE;">TICKET DESCRIPTION HERE</td>
               </tr>
             </tbody>
           </table>
         </td>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you for explaining the issue to me.

Answer (score 1):

Added  `z-index: 3; position: relative;` to the before element and `z-index: 0;` to the after element

```css
.container {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.progressbar {
  counter-reset: step;
}

.progressbar li {
  /*name of incomplete tasks */
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #7d7d7d;
}

.progressbar li:before {
  /*circle of incomplete tasks */
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  counter-increment: step;
  line-height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
 z-index: 3;
position: relative;

}

.progressbar li:after {
  /* line preceding incomplete tasks */
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  top: 12px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}

.progressbar li.done {
  /* check mark and name of completed tasks */
  color: #55b776;
}

.progressbar li.done:before {
  /* circles of completed tasks */
  border-color: #55b776;
  content: "\2713";
}

.progressbar li.done+li:after {
  /* line following completed tasks */
  background-color: #55b776;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<div style="width:650px; background-color:#EEEEEE;">
<header>
  <h1>
    COMPANY
  </h1>
  </header>
  <table width="95%" align="center" cellpadding="10" style="width:95%; background-color: #666666;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:15px">Case Number: 0000000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table cellpadding="10">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:35px">Date Opened: 10/31/2017 at 2:13 PM</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table width="95%" align="center" cellpadding="10" style="width:95%;background-color:white;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:20px;">
          You are receiving this email because your case has been updated. Your case details and any updates can be found below this message.
          <br /> If you wish to post a comment to the case you can simply reply to this email and your case will be updated. If you would like to include a screenshot or relevant log files you can do so by including them in your reply.
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" style="text-align: center;">
          <span class="container">
            <ul class="progressbar">
              <li class="done">Open</li>
              <li class="done">In Progress</li>
              <li>With Engineering</li>
              <li>Resolution Provided</li>
              <li>Closed</li>
            </ul>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:20px;">
      In order to proceed with your case we will need additional information or clarification on the reported issue. Please provide the requested information within the next 4 days. If no response is received during this time we will temporarily archive your
      case. Once you are ready to continue with simply reply to one of the case emails.
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
        <td>
           <table cellpadding="5" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td width="150" style="width:150px;background-color:#EEEEEE;padding-left:20px;border-left:10px solid white;">
                   <span style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">Subject</span>
                 </td>
                 <td width="350" style="width:350px;border:1px solid #EEEEEE;">TICKET TITLE HERE</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td width="150" style="width:150px; background-color:#EEEEEE;padding-left:20px;border-left:10px solid white;">
                   <span style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">Description</span>
                 </td>
                 <td width="350" style="width:350px;border:1px solid #EEEEEE;">TICKET DESCRIPTION HERE</td>
               </tr>
             </tbody>
           </table>
         </td>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
</html>
```